# How to change color of search menu in Start to black?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-search, themes

I'm talking about this:

[image: start-menu-search]

I already use Dark theme which works on most things:

[image: file-explorer-dark-mode]

But not when I search in Start menu

Basically what I'm looking for is command prompt like look (black background, white text)

My OS is LTSC 1809 (10.0.17763.437) for reference

Enterprise doesn't have Cortana, so I can't change any settings/registry related to it

Looking for internal solution (settings, regedit), but w/e else works is fine too

Thanks in advance

Side-question: is same possible for system menus (e.g. GPEdit, RegEdit, Control Panel, etc)

Answer (score 2):

Change Region
Type Regional Settings in the box, and when it appears.
Select a region where Cortana is not available. (eg. Gabon)
Select apply to that region.  This will change the color of the box.
Now, Sign out, and sign-in back.
Revert to original settings, but Cortana will retain its settings.

Or
Open regedit
Go to: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Search\Flighting\0\WhiteSearchBox
Change Value REG_DWORD to 0
Sign out and sign in again

Comment: Enterprise doesn't have Cortana as a result I have no key past "Flighting", I did add them artificially but they had no effect. [I have only these settings in for search](https://i.imgur.com/0IdJdSP.png)

Comment: If you reinstalled Enterprise from scratch and selected your region from the beginning, you might have more luck on this. But it is not reversible the way the above is.

Comment: I don't have Enterprise but also don't see the above registry key.